# I have added privacy policy to play store and my application. It’s been 10 hours my application didn’t publish again

Tags: android

I have used Admob in my application but i forgot to add privacy policy but now I added privacy policy to the application and playstore but the application didn't appear on playstore again.

Please guide my how to resolve this issue.

> Hi developers at Cmptrsntst,
>
> After review, The News Headlines, binarysole.com.thenewsheadlines, has
>   been removed from Google Play due to a policy violation. This app
>   won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.
>
> Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section
>   4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when
>   the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information.
>   We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android
>   advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy
>   requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must
>   provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the
>   Play Console, and from within the app.
>
> Next steps: Submit your app for another review
>
> Read through the Usage of Android Advertising ID and User Data
>   policies, as well as the Developer Distribution Agreement, and make
>   appropriate changes to your app. If you decide to collect sensitive
>   user information, be sure to abide by the above policies, and include
>   a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's store listing page and
>   within your app.  Make sure that your app is compliant with all other
>   Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if
>   there are further policy violations. Sign in to your Play Console and
>   submit the update to your app. Alternatively, you may opt-out of this
>   requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user
>   data.
>
> If approved, your app will again be available with all installs,
>   ratings, and reviews intact.
>
> If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this removal may have been in
>   error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my
>   colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.
>
> Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for
>   Google Play users.
>
> Regards,
>
> Justin
>
> The Google Play Team

Comment: Did you Publish the app again in the console?

Comment: I have generated a new apk file which includes privacy policy as well and uploaded to playcosole but still didn't get any response from the playstore team

Comment: I am trying to publish it but I can't do it anymore since I got that email from playstore Team

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same issue with one of my app and got same email because I hadn't included a privacy policy URL.

Now after I included the privacy policy URL and resubmitted the app from Store Listing, the app is now live after around 2 hours.

If you have already updated the privacy policy URL, make sure it is clear and it follows the Google's policies. Mention clearly that your app doesn't collect personally identifiable data.

Comment: Do we need to create new release with new build for policy update also?

Comment: @GaneshMatkam, I don't think so.